# Could I use "so much so that..." in this context?

Tags: grammar, sentence-usage

I was wondering if I could use "so much so that" in the following way

" I usually don't enter on Skype, **so much so that** I've just seen your message, and you sent it one week ago."

Thank you. It's a real example. I used it just like that and then it kept me wondering whether I could use it in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an awkward use of the idiom.  Usually, "so much so that" refers to a positive measurement of something, not the negative lack of something(as in your example).  The example provided by Google's online dictionary is:

> I was fascinated by the company, so much so that I wrote a book about it.

Another example of my own uses the volume of a fluid:

> He overfilled the car's gasoline tank, so much so that the floor is covered with gas.

The way I'd structure your phrase is:

> I rarely log onto Skype, it's so bad that I only just now saw your message, though you sent it a week ago.

In this case I'm using the idiom "it's so bad that," which is a negative version of the positive "so much so that."